# keystonejs. how to write a middleware for admin UI?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, keystonejs

Hello I am new to keystone js and am writing mongoose `plugin`.  I need a `hostname` in mongoose plugin.

Here my middleware hook to get hostname.

**routes/middleware.js**

```
exports.getHost = function(req, res, next) {
        keystone.set('host', req.headers.host);
    });
    next();
};
```

I can hook this middleware from client app.

**routes/index.js**

`keystone.pre('render', middleware.getHost);`

How do I hook this middleware for `/keystone/*` url which is for adminUI?

Comment: This is not currently possible, see https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/3187 for work towards a resolution